# How to create nested objects in GraphQL mutation?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, express-graphql

In GraphQL, I have two types, **Author** and **Quotes**, as follow:

```
  type Author {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    last_name: String!
    quotes: [Quote!]!
  }

  type Quote {
    id: Int!
    author: Author! 
    quote: String!
  }
```

In the implementation an **Author** and a **Quote** could be created individually.
But I want to add the functionality to create the author and multiple quotes in the same request as follows:

```
mutation{
  createAuthor(author:{
    name:"Kent",
    last_name:"Beck",
    quotes:[
      {
        quote: "I'm not a great programmer; I'm just a good programmer with great habits."
      },
      {
        quote: "Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work"
      }
    ]
  }) {
    id
    name
    quotes{ 
      quote
    }
  }
}
```

If the client want to merge the creation as shown above, what is the most perfect way of doing it?

The current implementation for ***author creation*** with multiple quotes is as follow:

```
resolve (source, args) {
    return models.author.build({
        name: args.author.name,
        last_name: args.author.last_name
    }).save().then(function(newAuthor) {
        const quotes = args.author.quotes || [];
        quotes.forEach((quote) => {
          models.quote.create({
            author_id: newAuthor.id,
            quote: quote.quote,
          });
        });

        return models.author.findById(newAuthor.id);
    });
}
```

Can I somehow invoke the **Quotes** creation mutations automatically?